# Canvas lines on different phones show different colors

Tags: javascript, canvas, mobile

[image: this is dark in a iphone6]

[image: this is white in another iphone]

In my code,I write var rgb='255'.But canvas lines on different phones show different colors.I don't know why it is.So I ask you, please tell me what I do. Thank you!

```
//banner cas
!function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById('cas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var rgb = '255';      // 线条颜色值
var extendDis = 5;   // 可超出的画布边界
var lineDis = 100;    // 连线距离
lineDis *= lineDis;
canvas.width = 1920;
canvas.height = 200;

  // 绘制点
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + rgb + ', ' + rgb + ', ' + rgb + ', 1';
  ctx.fillRect(dot.x - 0.5, dot.y - 0.5, 1, 1);
}
}();
```

Comment: My guess is one of them doesn't support `rgba`

Comment: can you add a working snippet

Comment: ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + rgb + ', ' + rgb + ', ' + rgb + ', 1';  or the missing closing bracket makes the string not parsable and it default to black.

Comment: I see. I really carelessly. Thank you very much!